# Why is META-INF called META-INF?

Tags: java, web-applications

I am trying to explain the fundamentals of web applications. I came across this question on META-INF and WEB-INF. How did those directories get those names?

Comment: How does any name come about? Somebody picked it, likely for the reasons Isaac mentioned. Capitalized it, b/c...., and then the name just sort of stuck. It's like asking why it's `http`, when it could have been `htp:`.. just a better meme, I suppose

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Jar files are actually ZIP files with extra information and possibly better indexing.  When packing the extra information into the ZIP file it becomes important to place it in a location which is not likely to conflict with normal ZIP file contents.

The selection of META-INF as a directory in which information about the JAR file could be stored was an attempt to use directories as a name space within the ZIP file.  Basically, if it was stored in META-INF, it was Meta-data Information, or (picking amongst the possible meanings of meta), "self information" or "abstract information".

This allowed the storage of information which would impact the handling of the ZIP file within the ZIP file itself, without breaking the ZIP file packaging.  This was key, as it prevented the need to create a new, portable compression format and popularize it for the purpose of Java code packaging.  As people became accustomed to the utility of META-INF, new "name spaces" in the ZIP file were created for specific packaging formats, for example "WEB-INF".

The first "extensions" to the ZIP file format was the addition of a manifest, or MANIFEST.MF and the optional addition of an index list (to speed item extraction).  Now such files (due to having a known extension name space) have been able to extend in many other ways, like the recent addition of the sub-directory "services" for service registration.

When you consider that ZIP files contain files and directories, it only makes sense to use a directory as a name space.

Comment: (Point of pedantry: Zip files only contain files and no directories. The file names can be quite long though.)

Comment: @Tom, true.  Zip's path to the file name serves as a directory entry.  The paths are then converted to directories on demand during extraction of the files.  As this "directory" is bound to a file, it still services the name space requirements for JAR files quite nicely; however, it does make it impossible to truly store a directory independently of a file in a ZIP archive.

Comment: Thanks! That was quite insightful. I too think that WEB-INF followed the META-INF convention.

Comment: @EdwinBuck, Then shouldn't it have been called `META-INFO` and `WEB-INFO` instead of `-INF`?

Comment: Totally guessing, but maybe it was to fit within the 8 character file name length limit in DOS?

Answer (score 7):

[Meta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta)

[Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_wide_web)

"Inf" I would imagine is short for "information."

Comment: The question asked how the directory names came about, not what they mean.

Comment: The title is "why is META-INF called META-INF" and I explained what each part of the hyphenated name means, two by links to Wikipedia articles and one by conjecture (I've never actually seen a scholarly reference for the "INF" designations, but every anecdote I could share indicates that it means "information."). If you're looking for a full etymology, english.stackexchange.com might be a better place, although I think they generally work with dictionary words, slang, and idioms.

Comment: @Geordee, I guess my understanding of the question is, why was it named WEB-INF as opposed to WEB-INFO for example.  Could you clarify your question?

Comment: "how it came about" is impossible for the user community to answer, unless anyone from Sun would like to elaborate

Comment: @jzd Again this is conjecture, but could it be because "META-INF" is 8 characters long, which has significance in our field, and "WEB-INF" allows for a common suffix without either exceeding 8 characters? Also, does it really matter?

Comment: I was wondering whether there is any conscious decision behind this name. You can see this in other packages too (EPUB for example, which just packages an XHTML file and a few metadata files). It could be something that someone decided while writing the specifications. I was inquiring whether there is something out there which I can't figure out from search. Another way of asking is whether META-INF originated from Java or was it being used even before that!

Comment: I guess I realize the triviality of the question. I did a deep search into 1990s and the results just say there should be a folder called META-INF. And that's it. Thanks everyone!

Comment: It's funny how, with things for computers, a few people, possibly a single person, can come up with something leaving millions of other people scratching their heads in wonder. That's far from democratic. You could say that people writing middleware and specifications are modern dictators.

Comment: @IsaacTruett, Do you have a source claiming INF = Information? "Inf" I would imagine is short for "inferior."

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly meta-inf is for meta information. This may be totally wrong. If that is correct you could probably guess that web-inf is for web information :-P